# handle replied message aiogram

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

How can I do this: I got my tgbot using `aiogram` and I need this bot to handle replied messages. For example: A user in chat replied some message and the bot should handle the users message and also the message that user replied.

I've tried:

```py
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.chat.id == chat_id, commands='add')
async def add_to_db(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сейчас добавлю')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    await state.finish()
```

That code reacts to command `'add'`, and I need the bot to learn which message was replied with this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

types.Message has attribute **reply_to_message** and it is types.Message object too:

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.chat.id == chat_id, commands='add')
async def add_to_db(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    # message.reply_to_message is a types.Message object too
    try:
        msg = message.reply_to_message.text # if replied
    except AttributeError:
        msg = 'not replied'
    
    await message.answer(f'Replied message text: {msg}')
    await message.answer(f'Message text: {message.text}')
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch, that solved my problem

Comment: You could mark my answer as "Accepted"

Comment: Better check `message.reply_to_message` for `None` instead of catching `AttributeError`. Imagine some time you may misspell an attribute like `text` as `txet` and won't find an error because of this `except AttributeError`.